# Doctrine Behaviours - Sortable on non relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-2.1, symfony-2.2

I am trying to sort by a property which is not in relation but part of current entity.

For some reason sortable wont work for me if property with @Gedmo\SortableGroup is part of current entitty.

Here is my Entity:

https://gist.github.com/rat4m3n/91df50da8c653edfa3d0

> use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
>
> use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
>
> ```
> /**
>  * @Gedmo\SortableGroup
>  * @ORM\Column(name="total_chips", type="integer")
>  */
> private $total_chips = 0;
>
>
> /**
>  * @Gedmo\SortablePosition
>  * @ORM\Column(name="ranking", type="integer")
>  */
> private $ranking = 0;
> ```

Is this simply not possible / supported ?

Else... how could I accomplish such behaviour in any other way?

Comment: You can use something like this, $products = $repository->findBy(
    array('name' => 'foo'),
    array('price' => 'ASC')
);

Comment: hmm no... thats not what i am after.. i need to update the filed based on value from another field in the same entity

Answer (score 0):

If you still have a problem with the SortablePosition and the SortableGroup feature of Gedmo, you can follow this :

1. **Do not affect values to the property.**
2. **Activate the features in the `config.yml`**

   stof_doctrine_extensions:
       default_locale: fr_FR
       orm:
           default:
               sortable: true
               tree: true
3. **And add the listener to your entity :**

```
namespace Acme\AcmeBundle;     
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AcmeAcmeBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function boot()
    {
        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.    default_entity_manager');

        $evm = $em->getEventManager();
        $evm->addEventSubscriber(new \Gedmo\Sortable\    SortableListener);
    }
}
```